# How is a constructor for a derived class supposed to be like in c++ when derived class has added data member

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I am new to c++. I have been trying to get past this error. I know when a class in derived, it inherits everything from the base class, but what if the derived class has other data members? How is the constructor suppose to be?

When I try putting only the new I try to pass parameters to the newly made class members in the constructor I get an error to say it doesn't match that of the base class. When I try using that of the base class and adding the new data members it tells me I am redefining. So I wonder whats left to do to get past this error below is my code.

This is the base class:

```
class movielibrarybase
{


public:
        movielibrarybase(string name, string dirname, string gen, int price);

        void setname(string name);
        string getname();

        void setdirector_name(string dirname);
        string getdirector_name();

        void setgenre(string gen);
        string getgenre();


        void setprice(int price);
        int getprice();

        void display();

        ~movielibrarybase();

    protected:
    string name;
    string director_name;
    string genre;
    int price;
};
```

And this is the derived class:

```
class songlibrary: public movielibrarybase
{
    public:
        songlibrary();


        void setartist_name(string name);
        string getartist_name();



        void setsong_position(string position);
        string getsong_position;

        ~songlibrary();


    protected:

    string artist_name;
    string song_postion;
};
```

I am getting the following errors:

songlibrary.cpp||In constructor 'songlibrary::songlibrary(std::string, std::string, std::string, int, std::string, std::string)':|
songlibrary.cpp|6|error: no matching function for call to 'movielibrarybase::movielibrarybase()'|
movielibrarybase.cpp|3|note: candidates are: movielibrarybase::movielibrarybase(std::string, std::string, std::string, int)|
movielibrarybase.h|8|note:                 movielibrarybase::movielibrarybase(const movielibrarybase&)|
songlibrary.cpp|34|error: no 'std::string songlibrary::getsong_position()' member function declared in class 'songlibrary'|

Comment: If your computer has a mouse, use it to copy the actual compiler messages and paste them to the question edit box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it would be something like:-

```
songlibrary::songlibrary( string n, string director, string gen, 
                          int pri, string artist, string song )

                     : movielibrarybase( n, director, gen, pri ), 
                       artist_name( artist ), song_postion( song )
```

One thing to note here is sequence in member initializer list matters. First calls should be to base classes and then derived classes members **should be initialized in the order in which they are declared in a class**.

Also, class members are initialized in the order of their declaration in the class, the order in which they are listed in a member initialization list makes not a whit of difference

Comment: The sequence in the member initializer list, as you mentioned in the second statement, does not matter. The only thing to be aware of is that using a different order in there will not change the effective initialization order (compilers often give a warning).

Comment: @E_net4 Sometimes it matters... I don't want to clutter this page with unnecessary details...raise a separate question and I would give you a sound example

Comment: Mind you, it is also part of my coding practise to keep the same order in each part. @ravi There is no need for a separate question, but now you made me curious about such an example. Maybe a chat room or another means of messaging would be fine.

Answer (score 3):

For that case you use the member initializer list in the constructor to invoke the right constructor in the base class:

```
 songlibrary::songlibrary(string name, string dirname, string gen, int price,
         string artist_name, string song_position)
 : movielibrarybase(name, dirname, gen, price), // initialize base class
   artist_name(artist_name), // initialize member in this class
   song_position(song_position) {
   // other ctor stuff
 }
```

If you do not state the parent class on that list, it will default to the default constructor. Since there is no default constructor in your `movielibrarybase` class, a compiler error occurred.